# NSDictionary id key value

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I recently try to change the Json library in my applicaiton from `SBJson` to the `NSJSONSerialization`.

When I do this job, I find there are some key value that I can not get out.

Here is an example of the `NSDictionary` I get after `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
 {

    id = 4028;

    "novel_author" = "XYZ";

    "novel_pub" = "ABC";

    "novel_title" = "DATE LIVE";

    updatedate = "2013-01-13 22:31:13";

    "vol_click" = 7563;

}
```

The original Json data string is:

```
{
   "id":"4028",
   "vol_click":"7563",
   "updatedate":"2013-01-13 22:31:13",
   "novel_author":"XYZ",
   "novel_pub":"ABC",
   "novel_title":"DATE LIVE"
}
```

I can not get the value of the key "id" out.
`[NSDictionary objectForKey@"id"]` is useless.

Is there anyone have idea how to get the value out?

Comment: `objectForKey` should work fine.

Comment: Yep, show your code, and where you NSLog the dictionary with respect to when yo do the `objectForKey`.  I'm no great fan of NSJSONSerialization, but it can't possibly be mucking this up.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell by the output of what looks like `NSLog("%@", dict);`, the JSON deserialization process works fine.

The dictionary contains a key called "id", so `[dict objectForKey:@"id"]` should also work fine.

I can only conclude that this isn't the actual cause of the trouble you're having.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just check the key and object value, and the @"id" still do not work. I think this might be something like <NSNull null>. You can show this in NSLog, however, using (null) as NSString to equal the value is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work:

```
        [yourDictName valueForKey:@"id"]
    [yourDictName objectForKey:@"id"]
```

If you can see the value using NSLog to display the dictionary, then it is there. Beyond that, make sure your object is not getting nil'd or released or freed.